# navigate to next view on image tap?

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-touch-theming

I am using dataview itemTpl to display my images (thumbnail view).

I am able to display the images properly. How can I add itemtap on these images?
So that when I tap on a particular image a new view is shown with the tapped image?

I tried this with controller but no luck. Can you help me solving this.

I am using Sencha Architect 2 for my example.

I am trying this code .Please correct me

**First View**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.galleryview',

    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'dataview',
                id: 'gallerythumbnail',
                layout: {
                    type: 'fit'
                },
                itemTpl: [
                    '<div class="lb-album">',
                    '    <ul>',
                    '        <li>',
                    '    <img src="{filename}" width="120px" heigth="120px"/>',
                    '        </li>',
                    '    </ul>   ',
                    '</div>'
                ],
                store: 'ImageStore'
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

**Second View - this view must be displayed when img is tapped**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.FullViewPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'carousel',
                id: 'mycarousel'
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

**Controller**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.GalleryController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            nav: 'galleryview'
        },

        control: {
            "dataview": {
                itemtap: 'viewFullScreen'
            }
        }
    },

    viewFullScreen: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, options) {
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('galleryview').push('MyApp.view.FullView');
        console.log(record);


    }

});
```

Thank You

Comment: Event delegation is probably what you're looking for:

Comment: "I tried this with controller but no luck". Could you show us the code of what you tried

Comment: I am trying this from last 3 hrs. I tried with controller and event delegation both,but no luck !!

Comment: if(current_data.xindex >= 0)
{
    Ext.Msg.alert("Opps!!!");
    
    /*var details = 'MyApp.view.ImageContainer';
    //this.push(details); 
     not able to push data from this view to other view  
    How to navigate/push data from this view to other ?
    (i am writing this code in itemTpl of Ext.Dataview using Sencha Architect) 
    */
    
    this.up('testpanel').push({xtype:'imagecontainer'});

}
else{
    Ext.Msg.alert("Opps!!!", "Something went wrong while calling data");
}

Comment: getting uncaught error : cannot call method 'push' of undefined can some help me finding solution for this. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to do it on image tap you can check for the event in that listener.

**Method 1**

```
listeners : {
    itemtap: function (list, index, item, record, senchaEvent) {
        if (senchaEvent.event.target.nodeName == 'IMG') {
            // Show next view
        }
    }
}
```

**I used like this**

```
Ext.create('Ext.List', {
                itemCls : 'my-dataview-item',
                id : 'myList',
                itemTpl : '<div><img src="' + localStorage.httpServerPrefix + '{imageURI}"/><span id="name">{fullname}</span></div>',
                store : aroundStore,
                listeners : {
                    itemtap: function (list, index, item, record, senchaEvent) {
                        if(senchaEvent.event.target.nodeName =='IMG') {
                            me.othersProfileImageClicked(record.data);
                        }
                        else
                            me.onMessageClickedInAround(list, record);                  
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Update**

```
listeners : {
    itemtap: function (dataview,index,target,record,e,option) {
        if (e.event.target.nodeName == 'IMG') {
            // Show next view
        }
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

You can use event delegation, Like this

```
Ext.create('Ext.List', {
      itemCls : 'my-dataview-item',
      id : 'myList',
      itemTpl : '<div><img src="' + localStorage.httpServerPrefix + '{imageURI}"/><span id="name">{fullname}</span>',
      store : aroundStore,,
      listeners: [{
            element: 'element',
            delegate: 'img',
            event: 'tap',
            fn: function() {
                alert('One!');
            }
        }
     ]
 });
```

Comment: :Thank you for sharing answer, but there is no senchaEvent in my code. I am using Sencha architect. What I get as param in itemTap function is as follows, can you please provide some help for below itemtap :function(dataview,index,target,record,e,option){           var store=Ext.getStore('TestStore');
store.load();
var current_store = dataview.getStore();
var current_data  = dataview.getStore().getAt(index).getData(); //this.up('testpanel').push({xtype:'imagecontainer'});} But this code is not working. I have img thunbnail on this dataview and on tap of image it should navigate Plz help

Comment: put this "alert(e.event.target.nodeName)" inside itemtap function and tell me what your getting

Comment: when you tab on image, what your getting in alert

Comment: when I tab on image I get IMG in alert

Comment: let me know, if your still having problem ?

Comment: i understood the IMG part. But I am still having a problem in navigation !!! I am getting error

Comment: uncaught error : has no method. How to navigate? what is me? 'this' is not working !!

Comment: I have written this var me = MyApp.view.TestPanel;
if(e.event.target.nodeName === 'IMG'){
    me.test(record.data);//what should come here?
}else{
    //
}

Comment: post the code, so that i can understand what your trying to do

Comment: what you want to do, within if

Comment: what i am trying to do is when i tap on the image it should be displayed in new view on the full screen of the platform

Comment: within if - want to display the selected image on next view (navigate to next screen)

Comment: where is test function?, i navigate to next view using     Ext.Viewport.add({xtype : 'replies'});

Comment: tell me where you written test function

Comment: you can't call like that, are you calling function written in view at controller?.

Comment: no. I tried using controller but no luck. I have updated my question please check and Please let me know

Comment: I am not able to fix this. Please check my updated post. Please share the solution. Thanks

Comment: Above answer is useful to check if tapped item is image or not. But I not not able to push data ., navigate from one screen to other on image tap.